# Assign FQDN for Internal Services in a Private Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, service, coredns, fqdn, rke

I setup a **private K8S cluster** with `RKE` `1.2.2` and so my K8S version is `1.19`. We have some **internal services**, and it is necessary to access each other using custom FQDN instead of simple service names. As I searched the web, the only solution I found is adding `rewrite` records for CoreDNS `ConfigMap` described in this [REF](https://coredns.io/2017/05/08/custom-dns-entries-for-kubernetes/). However, this solution results in manual configuration, and I want to define a record automatically during service setup. Is there any solution for this automation? Does CoreDNS have such an API to add or delete `rewrite` records?

**Note1**: I also tried to mount the CoreDNS's `ConfigMap` and update it via another pod, but the content is mounted read-only.

**Note2**: Someone proposed calling `kubectl get cm -n kube-system coredns -o yaml | sed ... | kubectl apply ...`. However, I want to automate it during service setup or in a pod or in an `initcontainer`.

**Note3**: I wish there were something like `hostAliases` for services, something called `serviceAliases` for internal services (ClusterIP).

Comment: In short, you were able to achieve what you want, but you are looking some kind of automation? You are looking pure kubernetes way or 3rd party software solution?

Comment: You are correct, PjoterS. I just want an automated way, and as you said, pure kubernetes way or 3rd party software solution is fine. Even, I'm ready to develop the code if there is any CoreDNS's API for the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no ready solution for this.

Only thing comes to my mind is to use [MutatingAdmissionWebhook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#mutatingadmissionwebhook). It would need catch moment, when new `Kubernetes service` was created and then modify `ConfigMap` for `CoreDNS` as it's described in [CoreDNS](https://coredns.io/2017/05/08/custom-dns-entries-for-kubernetes/) documentation.

After that, you would need to reload `CoreDNS` configuration to apply new configuration from `ConfigMap`. To achieve that, you can use `reload plugin` for `CoreDNS`. More details about this plugin can be found [here](https://github.com/coredns/coredns/issues/3928).

Instead of above you can consider using `sidecarContainer` for `CoreDNS`, which will send `SIGUSR1` signal to `CoreDNS` conatiner.
Example of this method can be found in [this Github thread](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/24957#issuecomment-632881383).